# Resizing a responsive site down and up again in Chrome doesn't reset some elements

Tags: html, css, wordpress, google-chrome

I've been working on the site http://www.realestatedevon.co.uk/ using Wordpress.

The site is responsive and works a treat generally, but in Chrome there's an annoying problem. When you shrink the browser down and then back up, the sidebar and right-side header content doesn't reset position - until hitting refresh.

I've found that if I select the div .site-main .sidebar-container styling in inspector and untick position:absolute and re-tick it, this also restores it. I haven't found a way to do the same with the header text on the right.

I'm relatively new to web dev so I may be doing something daft, but your help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Class `.site-main .sidebar-container` has `position: absolute` and doesn't have `right: 0`. Also, the parent container doesn't have `position: relative`.

Please read http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp

Comment: Thanks, this is definitely putting me on track, the issue is I need to keep the sidebar lined up with the top menu. I will take a look through the css_positioning article as soon as possible too!

Comment: Brill, I've added a right:3% style to the sidebar and that's sorted it :) Now I'll need to sort the header, hopefully it's a similar issue or something I can figure out from the w3schools article.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a place to put your own custom js code this is all you need:

```
$('.headerLogoRealEstate').on('resize', function(){
    if($(window).width>911){
        $(this).css('position', 'absolute');
    }
});
```

This will work on resize, and if your window width is greater than 911px it will put `position:absolute` on header.

Comment: Cheers for the suggestion. I'd like to use CSS if possible first but this alternate method is good to be aware of :)

Comment: I'm coding a lot in js lately so this was the first thing that popped in my mind :D Css is probably easier and better solution :)

Answer (score 0):

Rather than pursuing a javascript solution to quite an interesting CSS problem, I suggest that you better define your rules. When elements have a `fixed` or `absolute` position value, it's always best to be quite explicit. In each media query, try specifying `top` and `right` values.

Comment: Thanks, I'm having a play with the top and right positioning now (see above comment too re: lining up the sidebar with the menu).

Comment: Looks like the sidebar's working now, cheers for your input! :) Much to learn I still have

Answer (score 0):

Set right property value to the div which is absolutely positioned. Upon resize it will be positioned automatically. No need to add JS.

```css
.site-main .sidebar-container {
  right: 6%;
}
```